# SSIS Excel Source error: [Excel Source [1]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, visual-studio, ssis

I have a very simple SSIS Data Flow that Unions two Excel Sources together, does a small data conversion, and loads into a staging table.

However, my two Excel Sources are failing immediately as the Execute Phase begins.

I am only receiving the following nondescript errors:

```
[LA Report Source [627]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.

[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on component "LA Report Source" (627) returned error code 0xC0202009.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

[NOLA Report Source [640]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.

[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on component "NOLA Report Source" (640) returned error code 0xC0202009.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
```

This package had been working for several days, and suddenly started giving this error message a couple days ago, with no real changes to the data source.

In addition, when I go to preview the Excel Data Source, I get this weird error:
[image: Partial preview loads, then gives this error]

Any ideas?  Using Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to share the solution I came up with:

I was over-zealous with my SQL Query in the Excel Source.  I had a `WHERE` filter on my select statement, which worked for a little while, but an anomaly in the data must have thrown something off - SSIS didn't like it at all.

I've removed the `WHERE` portion, just leaving the `SELECT` portion, and I've handled the filter with a Conditional Split instead.  Problem solved!